# Getting error about SMTP with PHPMailer

Tags: php, html, smtp, phpmailer

I'm trying to reset my password and it's not working

Error:

> SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. Error: SMTP Error: Could not
>   authenticate.

I am using below code for sending email:

```
<?php
  require_once ("PHPMailer_v5.1\class.phpmailer.php");
  $Correo = new PHPMailer();
  $Correo->IsSMTP();
  $Correo->SMTPAuth = true;
  $Correo->SMTPSecure = "tls";
  $Correo->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
  $Correo->Port = 587;
  $Correo->Username = "foo@gmail.com";
  $Correo->Password = "123456";
  $Correo->SetFrom('foo@gmail.com','De Yo');
  $Correo->FromName = "From";
  $Correo->AddAddress("foo@gmail.com");
  $Correo->Subject = "testing PHPMailer";
  $Correo->Body = "<H3>it works!</H3>";
  $Correo->IsHTML (true);
  if (!$Correo->Send())
  {
    echo "Error: $Correo->ErrorInfo";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Message Sent!";
  }
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Frank Parts C.A. - Módulo de Recuperación de Contraseña</title>

<!-- bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assests/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- bootstrap theme-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assests/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <!-- font awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assests/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <!-- custom css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom/css/custom.css">  

  <!-- jquery -->
    <script src="assests/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- jquery ui -->  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assests/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css">
  <script src="assests/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <!-- bootstrap js -->
    <script src="assests/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
      <form class="form-signin" method="POST">

      <?php if(isset($smsg)){ ?><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> <?php echo $smsg; ?> </div><?php } ?>
      <?php if(isset($fmsg)){ ?><div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> <?php echo $fmsg; ?> </div><?php } ?>
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">¿Olvidó su Contraseña?</h2>
        <br> <br>
        <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
      <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre de Usuario" required>
    </div>
    <br><br><br>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Recuperar Contraseña</button>
        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" href="index.php">Iniciar Sesión</a>
      </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm using PHP Mailer, tried different codes but nothing works..

Can anyone help me?

Comment: try with different port;

Answer (score 0):

It happen because Password contain special character. I tried using "\"before special character like Password="djgh\^dfgfjk". But it didn't help me.
I just create new id and simple password without any special character and amazingly it's work.
Use password with out special character.

Comment: it has a simple password and it's not working. I tried with a new user and simple password.. same error